# Why do I get ‘does not implement abstract member’ warning while using kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel, kotlinx

I am getting this error while trying to read the bundle from another fragment where I am sending the NewVehicle object.

Error : Class 'NewVehicle' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun describeContents(): Int defined in android.os.Parcelable

**NewVehicle.kt**

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class NewVehicle(
    @SerializedName("av_se")
    val avSe: String,
    .....
    @SerializedName("vh_ob")
    val vhOb: String,
    @SerializedName("zo_in")
    val zoIn: String
):Parcelable{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it resolved by adding this in my build.gradle(app) inside the android block.

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: Last changed:
androidExtensions {
        isExperimental = true
}

Answer (score 16):

In my case I forgot to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'` in gradle

Comment: And which gradle file would I throw this in? Gotta be more specific than that.

Answer (score 5):

In my case just apply these plugins **in this order:**

Make sure that you call `kotlin-parcelize` **first** then `kotlin-kapt`

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'    
}
```

Answer (score -7):

Please remove {} after Parcelable.

```
@Parcelize
data class NewVehicle(
    @SerializedName("av_se")
    val avSe: String,
    .....
    @SerializedName("vh_ob")
    val vhOb: String,
    @SerializedName("zo_in")
   val zoIn: String
): Parcelable
```